# Changing the array value above the first non-zero element in the column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for vectorized way to changing the array value above the first non-zero element in the column.

```
for x in range(array.shape[1]):
    for y in range(array.shape[0]):
        if array[y,x]>0:
            break
        else:
            array[y,x]=255
```

[In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzpFD.png)

[Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqEIT.png)

Comment: Can you post an example of `array`? Generally, you can use `np.where()` to identify indices that satisfy a certain condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote about an *array* (not a *DataFrame*), I assume that you have
a *Numpy* array and want to use *Numpy* methods.

To do your task, run the following code:

```
np.where(np.cumsum(np.not_equal(array, 0), axis=0), array, 255)
```

Example and explanation of steps:

1. The source array:

   ```
   array([[0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 1],
          [1, 1, 0],
          [1, 0, 0]])
   ```
2. `np.not_equal(array, 0)` computes a boolean array with *True* for
   elements != 0:

   ```
   array([[False,  True, False],
          [False, False,  True],
          [ True,  True, False],
          [ True, False, False]])
   ```
3. `np.cumsum(..., axis=0)` computes cumulative sum (*True* counted as *1*)
   along axis *0* (in columns):

   ```
   array([[0, 1, 0],
          [0, 1, 1],
          [1, 2, 1],
          [2, 2, 1]], dtype=int32)
   ```

​4. The above array is a **mask** used in *where*. For masked values (where
the corresponding element of the mask is *True* (actually, *!= 0*)),
take values from corresponding elements of *array*, otherwise take *255*:

```
    np.where(..., array, 255)
```

The result (for my array) is:

```
array([[255,   1, 255],
       [255,   0,   1],
       [  1,   1,   0],
       [  1,   0,   0]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,that's what I was looking for. 2ms instead of 300 :D

Answer (score 0):

Use masking:

```
array[array == 0] = 255
```

Comment: This is super fancy.

Comment: This changes all values of array with value of 0 to 255.
This isn't what the question asked to solve (please read the question again and look at the code posted)

Comment: Hmm... The code is not is sync what is being asked.